# Can't do arithmetical operations on array values in c#

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, operation

I'm writing a program for homework, but I have stumbled upon a very hard problem for me.
Now, I'm pretty new to C#, so please bear with me. This may be really easy and obvious.
On-topic:
C# doesn't allow me to perform arithmetical operations on multidimensional array values:

```
if(map[0,1] - map[0,0] == 10)
```

This statement doesn't return a value, but instead throws me an error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first declare the array.  Example:

```
var map = new int[2,2];
```

creates a two-dimensional array with four integer elements.

Comment: Thanks! I knew I was doing a pretty stupid mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

the error sounds like you didn't initiate the values of the array
also don't forget that you took [,] arrays

```
int[,] example = new int[,] { {11,5}, {1,10} };//initiate the array
if (example[0,0]-example[1,0] == 10)
{

}
```